# Derivation of the target upper-bound with Jensen's inequality in 'Divide-and-Conquer RL'

Tags: reinforcement-learning, kullback-leibler, inequality

I am currently stuck in one line in the paper named ["Divide-and-Conquer Reinforcement Learning"(Ghosh et. al., 2018 ICLR)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.09874.pdf). It is the equation (1) in the page 4 which is like below.

$$E_\pi[D_{KL}(\pi \Vert \pi_c)] \leq \sum_{i,j}\rho(\omega_i)ρ(\omega_j )E_{\pi_i}[D_{KL}(\pi_i\Vert \pi_j )]$$
Here, the **policy in the Augmented MDP**(with context information added to the state) **$\pi$ is the family of context-wise policies**(which I assume it means it will just use the context specific policy when given the context info), **$\pi_c$ is the policy in the original MDP without the context info which is represented as the weighted**(weight is the context belief distribution given state)**sum of the context-wise policies that are in the family $\pi$.**

Although I understand the basic concept, I still cannot understand how this inequality is driven. Especially when defining the $\pi_c$, there were no comments on $\rho(w)$ and it should not since it is for the original MDP without any contextual information...

More info:

- w : context where it determines the initial state distribution
- $\rho$ : initial state distribution
- $\pi$ : $(\pi_i)^n_{i=1}, \pi_i$ =context-wise policy
- $\pi_c$ : $\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} p(\omega |s)\pi_\omega,p(\omega|s)$= belief distribution of what context the state is in.